# Matrix de Correlação no R (cov.wt)

Tags: r, matriz

Na função cov.wt no R é possivel obter como resultado somente a matrix de Correlação ?

cov.wt = Returns a list containing estimates of the weighted covariance matrix and the mean of the data, **and optionally of the (weighted) correlation matrix**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lendo [o código fonte](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/cov.wt.R) da função `cov.wt` vi referências para as funções [`cov2cor` e `cor`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.html). Caso essas funções não retornem o exato mesmo resultado da função acima você pode implementar sua própria solução reaproveitando o código fonte linkado. É claro que você também pode simplesmente descartar os demais resultados e ficar apenas com a matriz de correlação:

```
cor <- cov.wt(xy, wt = w1, method = "ML", cor = TRUE)$cor
```

Comment: É isso ai era só colocar $cor no final, obrigado.
cov.wt serve melhor para o que eu quero que é uma correlação ajustada exponencialmente.